# Appending text into a list via iteration

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am trying to append a colour into a list depending on the different situations. There are 4 possibilities in total outlined below. However, I am experiencing KeyError = 0 at the very first if statement:

```
col =[] 
x = df2["Prog Passes"]/df2["90s"]
y = df2["Prog Carr"]/df2["90s"] 

for i in range(0, len(x)): 
    if x[i]<=x.mean & y[i]<=y.mean: 
        col.append('yellow')   
    elif x[i]>=x.mean & y[i]<=y.mean: 
        col.append('green')
    elif x[i]<=x.mean & y[i]>=y.mean: 
        col.append('blue')
    else: 
        col.append('magenta')
```

Any ideas why this is arising and how I could possibly solve this?

EDIT:

@bici-sancta. Thanks! That looks promising. I tried that and I am getting an error:

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Here is my code:

```
df2["PP90"]= df2["Prog Passes"]/df2["90s"]
df2["PC90"]= df2["Prog Carr"]/df2["90s"]
x = df2["PP90"]
y = df2["PC90"]
df2["Colour"] = "red"
df2.loc[x<x.mean() & y<y.mean(), "Colour"] = 'yellow'
df2.loc[x>x.mean() & y<y.mean(), "Colour"] = 'blue'
df2.loc[x<x.mean() & y>y.mean(), "Colour"] = 'green'
df2.loc[x>x.mean() & y>y.mean(), "Colour"] = 'magenta'
df2
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: `x[i].mean` should be `x.mean()`

Comment: @Barmar Cheers, that's what I had initially, I changed it to see if it solved anything (it didn't). I've changed it back to the original, thanks for flagging that up.

Comment: @SanthiCazorla can you share the whole code?

Comment: I don't really know pandas well, but maybe you're supposed to use `.loc` or `.iloc` here.

Comment: @jade jamig This is pretty much the beginning of it. df2 is just a dataframe, that I have imported from Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is an example of what you are trying to accomplish.
You can extract the last column of the dataframe ('color') into a list, if needed after completed. I used a simple test on value, but you can easily substitute for the mean values

For multiple condition testing, use parentheses around each test condition ...
`df2.loc[(x<x.mean()) & (y<y.mean()), "Colour"]`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'a' : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'b':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]})

df['a_div_b'] = df['a'] / df['b']

# set default color (at one extreme of the value condition test)
df['color'] = 'red'

# successively change colors based on incremental increase in quotient value
df.loc[df['a_div_b'] > 1, 'color'] = 'blue'
df.loc[df['a_div_b'] > 2, 'color'] = 'magenta'
df.loc[df['a_div_b'] > 3, 'color'] = 'cyan'

print(df)
```